# Configuration class - best practice with Guice

Tags: java, configuration, guice

Background: I'm using Google Guice and so it's easier to pass through the configuration class but I think this is not the best way.

I have a configuration class which stores some paths:

```
class Configuration{
   String getHomePath();
   String getUserPath();
}
```

Also I have a class "a" which needs the "homepath" and a class "b" which needs the "userpath".

Is it better to pass the configuration class through the constructor of class a and b or only pass through the specific path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single answer to your question, there are only options to choose from, based on your specific situation.

If you know your `Configuration` class is going to grow **AND** if it's likely for your `A` and `B` classes will use more from it, then pass the whole `Configuration` object to their constructors. NB: I know this is against the YAGNI principle but sometimes you may know you're gonna need it ;-)

Otherwise, you can consider using `@Named` injection of your paths so that you reduce `A` and `B` classes dependencies to their minimum, which is a good design practice.

Answer (score 3):

If you're really using Guice correctly all your configuration like this should appear in modules' `configure` method. So:

1. Remove the configuration class.
2. Create annotation classes, probably called `HomePath` and `UserPath`.
3. Where class a uses `getHomePath()` replace that with a String field member named homePath.
4. Where class b uses `getUserPath()` replace that with a String field member named userPath.
5. Modify the class a and b constructors to be `@Inject` annotated (should already be) and take in a String parameter, respectively annotated with `@HomePath` and `@UserPath` and assign the String field member that injected value.
6. Create bindings in your module's configure method use [`.annotatedWith()`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) which define correct values; if they're only available at run time, bind a provider.

E.G.

```
class a {
  private String homePath;
  @Inject
  public a(@HomePath String homePath) {
    this.homePath = homePath;
  }
  public String tellMeAboutHome() {
    return "We live in a nice home called " + homePath;
  }
}

class customModule extends AbstractModule {
  public static final String userPath = "/home/rafael";

  public void configure() {
    bind(String.class).annotatedWith(HomePath.class).to("/home/");
    bind(String.class).annotatedWith(UserPath.class).to(userPath);
  }
}
```

If creating annotations is too much work for you, use the @Named annotation Guice [ships with](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#@Named).

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is code to make the dependency graph (which classes know about or depend on other classes/ interfaces) as simple, regular and fixed as possible.

If not passing the Configuration class makes a or b have zero dependencies on on user-written classes, or is necessary to avoid a dependency loop, then use the individual path strings. Otherwise, if it makes more sense to say 'this class has access to configuration info, in a way that may change in the future', pass the class.

I'd avoid the singleton approach, especially if you already have Guice set up.